# java .net. ConnectException: Connection refused

Tags: java, http

1. I'm trying to make a http call, if i set "localost:8090" in my URL,
   the code work
       If i set an external ip the code dont work.

   ```
   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
       at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
       at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
       at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
       at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
       at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
       at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
       at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
   ```

the code is this

```
   URL url = new URL("http://www.searchinquire.com/");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                (conn.getInputStream())));

            String output;
            System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(output);
            }

            conn.disconnect();

          } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

          } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

          }
```

Comment: The code works perfectly for me

Comment: are you able to open that external url in your browser ?

Comment: yes the url is http://www.searchinquire.com/, it is a normal http Url

Comment: that's strange, is the above stacktrace the full one ? if there are any `Caused By`s post them

Comment: at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)

Comment: this is the end pf my  stacktrace

Comment: are you behind some kind of a proxy ? firewall ? are you able to open the url in the browser without any proxies/vpns and with the firewall you have(if you have one) ?